# Powershell - how to create directories based on last modify date of files?

Tags: date, powershell

I'm new to PS. I've found scripts that scan directories (or recursive dirs) and gets the last modified date attribute of a file, but I can't create directories based on this date. What I'm trying to accomplish is something like this:

Date-----------File

2012-01-03   fax1.mfs

2012-01-04   fax2.mfs

2012-01-04   fax3.mfs

Create the following directories:

2012-01-03

2012-01-04

Once we have this we can use another script to move files based on their last modify date.

This is what I've created so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\path | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime.tostring("MM-dd-yyyy")}
```

Which gives the date in a string format MM-dd-yyyy. I just need to pass that as a variable to something like

```
| % {New-Item -Name ($_).tostring("MMddyyyy") -ItemType directory}
```

which errors out and doesn't create any directories.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the same at Mad Tom Vane, but pulls LastWriteTime as a seperate pipeline stage and calls NewItem with explicit property values. Less concise but arguably a tiny bit more readable.

```
$p = "h:\temp\240214"

get-childitem -Path $p | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime | 
        foreach-object { 
            New-Item -Path $p 
                -Name $_.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
                -ItemType Directory 
                -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
```

To address the follow up question of moving files into appropriate folder...

```
$p = "h:\temp\240214"

get-childitem -Path $p |
    Where-Object { ! ($_.PSIsContainer) } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $newDir = join-path $p ($_.LastWriteTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        New-Item -Path $newDir  `
            -ItemType Directory `
            -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $newDir
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, andyb! You guys ROCK!!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$Path = 'C:\temp\path'
Get-ChildItem $Path | Foreach-Object {mkdir "$Path\$($_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
```

Comment: Okay, follow up question: I thought I had a script that would move the files into those directories once they were created, but I don't (I can only move them into a static directory with the "move-item -destination "<path>" command).  How would I move all files from 2012-01-03 into the 2012-01-03 directory?